# Make Command Button Flat in VB6

Tags: button, vb6

I just want to ask how can I make my command button into flat button. Because even if I set the appearance into flat, it will still looks like a 3d.

Comment: activeX component inside the toolbox is the default. you need to build new OCX for that command button, e.g. LVbuttons

Comment: Microsoft lets his vb developer to develop other OCX and start to earn bucks with it. that's fair, I think. Now, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried LVbuttons that Jean said but I still it look likes 3d.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered an Image or PictureBox control?

Answer (score 0):

Use a label instead of command button.

Comment: But I want it to have a picture.